# Unable to connect to MongoLab "auth fails" error

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I am new to mongo. Recently created an account in mongoLab.

I am trying to connect to the database using the below statement.

```
mongo ds039487.mongolab.com:39487/webbies -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

Getting the below error

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: ds039487.mongolab.com:39487/webbies
Wed Dec 11 22:30:16.686 Error: 18 { code: 18, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth fails" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:228
exception: login failed
```

Note:
dbuser - is an User created in mongoLab

What is missing in this? Kindly advice.

Comment: Typically this is due to mistakingly using your mongolab.com username and password, instead of the database username and password, but if that's not the case you should write into support@mongolab.com.

Comment: Don't forget to **Add Database user** in mlab also https://i.stack.imgur.com/JymGw.png

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to pneumee.

The issue was because I was using my mongolab.com username and password, instead of the database username and password.

It is working now.

Comment: Excellent! Happy mongo'ing. :)

Answer (score 44):

Old thread, but just in case it helps anyone else: my problem was using shell version 2.4.9 to connect to mongo db version 3.0.7 (http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#mongo_shell).

Updating my shell sorted it (https://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: This helped me too! Thanks!

Comment: this should be actual solution.

Answer (score 12):

OK - I figured it out and would also like to add onto pneumee's answer.

1. Go to mongolab.com
2. Login.
3. Navigate to the "Users" tab.
4. If you have forgotten your Username and Password for the database, I suggest you "Add a new user" and supply it with the username and password.

[image: db username and db password]

Answer (score -6):

default users in db

```
login: admin 
password: admin
```

check users in 
https://mongolab.com/databases/MYDBNAME#users

my problem was being putting login and password mongolab