# MongoDB CLI authentication failed on mongoHQ hosted on Nodejitsu

Tags: mongodb, passwords, nodejitsu

I have an app on Nodejitsu with a MongoHQ database that is working.
Now I wish to see and manage my DB from my terminal. Here is the code I write:

```
mongo troup.mongohq.com:10014/database -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

The problem is I don't know whats my username and password. All I get from Nodejitsu is the MongoHQ username and Password but thats not correct.

Basically - How do I get my username and password for the DB - as stated in this question -

[Unable to connect to MongoLab "auth fails" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525435/unable-to-connect-to-mongolab-auth-fails-error)

Currently I am getting -

```
Error: 18 { code: 18, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth fails" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:228
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default I believe Mongo tries to connect to the admin database. You should ensure that the user has the correct permissions usually readWrite.  If that user is responsible only for a specific database consider doing the following from the CLI:

```
 mongo troup.mongohq.com:10014/database -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>   --authenticationDatabase <databasename>
```

If however that user will be responsible for multiple databases. You should update the privileges for that user.  More at the MongoDb docs [Create the system user administrator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#create-the-system-user-administrator) and  [privileges](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/)

Answer (score 0):

Click on Admin, then choose the Users tab, add a user by typing a username and password into the "db.addUser" box. Then use your newly created user account to connect.

Comment: Hey - Thanks! When I do that I get this - 
Error while trying to show server startup warnings: not authorized on admin to execute command { getLog: "startupWarnings" }

Comment: Did you ever figure out what that startup warnings message means?  I'm getting it now.